# Neo4j Cypher, exclude relationship from counting in variable-length path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We can limit a variable-length `FIRST|SECOND` path using this pattern:

```
(a)-[r:FIRST|SECOND*..3]->(b)
```

But what is the best way to return `FIRST|SECOND` paths that contain up to 3 `SECOND` relationships?

Comment: How does your graph looks like? How the nodes are connected? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be a very hard problem. Your use case does not allow there to be an upper bound on the variable-length path pattern (which is normally [best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663220/cypher-unlimited-path-length-and-large-path-length-queries-hang/61666860#61666860)), because the first (or second, or third) `SECOND` relationship could appear after *any number* of relationships.

Although the following query does not impose any upper bounds, it also does not attempt to extend a subpath any further after finding each `SECOND` relationship. So it **avoids needlessly searching to the end of every possible path**. The `FIRST*0..` syntax use a [zero lower bound](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#zero-length-paths) and means "match paths having 0 or more consecutive `FIRST` relationships".

This query is able to find all paths with up to 3 `SECOND` relationships by chaining together 3 separate subpath queries, and then using the APOC method [apoc.path.combine](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.path/apoc.path.combine/) to stitch together the subpaths into the final full paths. The `NULL` checks are used to ignore subpaths that found no match.

```
MATCH (a:Test {testid: 1})
OPTIONAL MATCH p1=(a)-[:FIRST*0..]->()-[:SECOND]->(b)
OPTIONAL MATCH p2=(b)-[:FIRST*0..]->()-[:SECOND]->(c)
OPTIONAL MATCH p3=(c)-[:FIRST*0..]->()-[:SECOND]->(d)
WITH p1, p3,
  CASE WHEN p2 IS NOT NULL THEN apoc.path.combine(p1, p2) END AS p12
WITH p1, p12,
  CASE WHEN p3 IS NOT NULL THEN apoc.path.combine(p12, p3) END AS p123
WITH (COLLECT(p1) + COLLECT(p12) + COLLECT(p123)) AS paths
UNWIND paths AS p
RETURN p
```

Caveat: this query is not efficient unless most paths contain at least 3 `SECOND` relationships. If that is not what your graph looks like, then create a new question providing details of your data model and how densely it is populated with `SECOND` nodes. Your data model may need to be modified.

Comment: This is very cool solution. My only comment is that if we have `(a)-[:SECOND]->(myCoolNode)`, without a `FIRST` between a and myCoolNode, I don't think this will find that path. Easy add-on to find those too though. Well done!

Comment: Actually, `(a)-[:FIRST*0..]->()-[:SECOND]->(b)` matches `(a)-[:SECOND]->(b)` if there is no `FIRST` relationship.

Comment: Oh because you started with 0. You are very clever! Always a pleasure to read your solutions. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases I can think of.

a. `SECOND` is the last relationship linked to b. Something like this:

```
(a)-[:FIRST]->()-[:SECOND]->()-[:SECOND]->()-[:SECOND]->(b)
```

For this, you can try this query:

```
MATCH path=(a)-[r:FIRST|SECOND*1..]->()-[:SECOND]->(b)
WHERE SIZE([r1 in relationships(path) WHERE type(r1) = 'SECOND' | r1]) = 3
RETURN path
```

In this query, I fix the last relationship linked to `b` is of type 'SECOND', and we check whether the count of `SECOND` relationships is 3.

b. Another case is, any relationship can be linked to `b` at the end of the path, provided you have 3 `SECOND` relations on the path. Something like this:

```
(a)-[:SECOND]->()-[:SECOND]->()-[:SECOND]->()-[:FIRST]->(b)
```

For this case, try the following query:

```
 MATCH path=(a)-[r:FIRST|SECOND*1..]->(b)
 WHERE SIZE([r1 in relationships(path) WHERE type(r1) = 'SECOND' | r1]) = 3
 RETURN path
```

As noted by @cybersam in the comments, to avoid out-of-memory errors, you should put an upper bound in the pattern match, which suits your purpose. Also, if upto 3 `SECOND` relationships are required, then this query will work:

```
 MATCH path=(a)-[r:FIRST|SECOND*1..10]->(b)
 WHERE SIZE([r1 in relationships(path) WHERE type(r1) = 'SECOND' | r1]) <= 3
 RETURN path
```

Note, I have provided an upper limit of 10 here, you can modify it accordingly.

Comment: There can be paths like this
(a)-[:FIRST]->()-[:SECOND]->()-[:FIRST]->()-[:SECOND]->(b). The order of relations is undefined, so what to do in that case?

Comment: If you just want 3 `SECOND` relations in the path, use the second query, regardless of their order. And, if you want 3 `SECOND` relations in the path, with one of them at the end of the path, use 1st query.

Comment: To avoid running forever or out of memory, it is [best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663220/cypher-unlimited-path-length-and-large-path-length-queries-hang/61666860#61666860) to impose an upper bound on variable length patterns. Also, his original query wanted _up to_ 3, not only 3.